# UI framework for angular 12 project

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, primeng, bootstrap-5

We are going to create a new project on angular 12. I need suggestions to choose the UI framework.

We have options of bootstrap 5, angular material, and primeNg.

I have done the below research:

Bootstrap 5 is good for beginner developers, and responsive, but not useful to create any complex components. Developers have to do it manually.

Angular Material is good for theming, and providing good widgets but does not have any type of inbuilt chart and responsive support.

PrimeNg is good for simple and complex components which provides all types of widget charts, complex grids, tabs. It has all the packages, responsiveness. But, it does not provide any customization.

This is what I have done analysis.

Our requirement is that we do not want to create unnecessary complex component so that we can focus on data which support readymade components and want to avoid multiple libraries. We will require the support of i18n and accessibility feature support as well.

Any recommendations or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://angular.io/resources?category=development you can see more ui libraries on this link.pls have a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used all 3 libraries you mention and others. My thoughts on your observations.

Bootstrap - waste of space, very old school and boring looking. It's grid system made it famous but CSS grid now means its redundant.

Angular Material - Professional components but customization and overly complex markup can become a real pain. For example, if you want to add custom buttons in the datepicker modal then you need a degree and 2 days to add them! If you are doing nothing outside the norm then its bareable.

primeng - Nice lib and easy to integrate with but little customization is available. Also, components can be inconsistent. For example, one may require you to style the width with CSS and the next one provides a width input property. Also, upgrading between versions can really break the look and feel of your app.

As much as I hate it (and I really do) and am really peeved that the top Angular lib is so painful to work with (really painful), and due to lack of decent competition, I would recommend Angular Material.

However, if you want some other ideas then look at [Rising Stars](https://risingstars.js.org/2020/en#section-angular)

In particular, NG-ZORRO, is pretty popular. However, for me personally, it suffers similar issues to primeng.

All in all, a component lib should meet most your needs. However, there's always gonna be something extra whacky that you need to implement and for these one off's an additional lib that specializes in that specific area is usually a must.

All the best.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. 
The main concern also comes where it becomes difficult to choose the framework 
which provides more customization in terms of overriding styling which should match with UX design.
If we go with any primeNg or angular material and it becomes headache to update framework styling.
without much usage of ViewEncapsulation.None

Answer (score 4):

If your client or organization is ready to buy the premium version, you can go with kendo controls, which gives you web & mobile responsive controls.

With kendo controls, you can also add bootstrap 5 for other CSS changes.

With these 2 frameworks, you can satisfy your requirements.

I hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: We need open source platform.

Comment: then you can go with angular material. We have developed a huge project with only 2 frameworks, bootstrap 5 & angular material. these 2 were enough for us.

Comment: is it possible to create complex component and do more customization using angular material? and how it is easy to create complex component like nested grid, tree structure? Because primeNg provides charts and all readymade if we go with angular material,  we will have to choose chart from another library?

Comment: Nested grid is not available in these universal frameworks for that you have to install extra libraries or go with the premium version.

Comment: yes if you are using a free or open-source version then you have to also add more libraries as per your requirements.